# MVC2 hidding the textbox and label depending on the db result

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on mvc2 , I just dont know how to use visible property in mvc2 like I use in webforms, I want to set the label and texbox to be visible on the view if one of the db field is true , if not then the view should not render label and textbox, in other words should not be visible, IT was quite straightforward in webforms but how to get this working in mvc2 , any ideas or suggesstion will be appreciated thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put an if statement in the view and render the TextBox or the Label depeding on db value.

```
<%if(item.myField){%>
...render textbox
<%}else{%>
..render label
<%}%}
```